# CRM 2015 set more rows for subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015, setting, subgrid

How to set subgrid properties in CRM 2015 quote, to show more than 7 rows table (table height more than 7 rows)? 
I spend a lot of time to find anwer to my question but I found nothing.

I try to set number of rows and "automatically expand to use available space" in form settings, but subgrid height is still max 7 rows.

When "automatically expand to use available space" is unchecked, huge space apears, but subgrid still has height 7 rows.

[subgrid and space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNl9A.png)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a "feature" of the out-of-the-box editable subgrid on quote (as well as order and invoice).

As a workaround you could delete the standard subgrid and add a new subgrid (using the same view). This will result in:

- You will be able to change the number of rows (by specifying the number of rows and unchecking "Automatically expand to use available space."
- As a downside, you will not be able to add write-in products or use inline editing.